# Pandas Selection into iterable variable?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Big picture of what I'm trying to accomplish is this:

I want to select the parts we've sold at a loss, put them into a list, then iterate through the list and use the .agg() to do some analysis.

Here's a link to a sample CSV file with some data and sample output:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4xdnV0LFZI1RktqR0dVWVZEYkU

And here's my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame
df =  pd.read_csv('SO_Sample.csv')
dfLoss = df[(df['Profit/Loss'] < 0)]

part_count = pd.DataFrame
part_count =   (dfLoss.groupby(['Part','Rev'])[['Serial_No']].count())
print(part_count)
```

I get a result set and here's where I get stuck.

I don't know how to assign pairs of iterable variables from grouped selections in Pandas.  Once I can do that I want to loop through the original df and get historical summary data for the part and rev combinations.

That leads me to what may be a second question, the combine piece of the Pandas puzzle - to have the data returned all put together.

The end output would look like this:

```
Part    Rev    Serial_No    Profit/Loss    Count    Min    Max    Mean    Std
```

The ['Part', 'Rev', 'Serial_No', 'Profit/Loss'] would be from the original df and then the ['count', 'min', 'max', 'mean', 'std'] would all be the aggregate from all the historical part records.

If this is indeed a second question I'll post it separately, but I am pulling my (little bit) of hair out trying to figure out the first part of this.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
In [48]: (df[df[['Part','Rev']].isin(dfLoss[['Part','Rev']]).all(1)]
    ...:    .groupby(['Part','Rev','Serial_No'])
    ...:    .agg({'Profit/Loss':['count','min','max','std']})
    ...: )
    ...:
Out[48]:
                        Profit/Loss
                              count   min   max std
Part      Rev Serial_No
Table leg a   S12369              1 -19.0 -19.0 NaN
          b   S12349              1 -34.0 -34.0 NaN
          c   S12359              1 -57.0 -57.0 NaN
Widget    a   S12345              1  -4.0  -4.0 NaN
wrench    a   S12360              1 -99.0 -99.0 NaN
          b   S12370              1 -22.0 -22.0 NaN
          c   S12350              1 -15.0 -15.0 NaN
```

or:

```
In [49]: (df[df[['Part','Rev']].isin(dfLoss[['Part','Rev']]).all(1)]
    ...:    .groupby(['Part','Rev','Serial_No'], as_index=False)
    ...:    .agg({'Profit/Loss':['count','min','max','std']})
    ...: )
    ...:
Out[49]:
        Part Rev Serial_No Profit/Loss
                                 count   min   max std
0  Table leg   a    S12369           1 -19.0 -19.0 NaN
1  Table leg   b    S12349           1 -34.0 -34.0 NaN
2  Table leg   c    S12359           1 -57.0 -57.0 NaN
3     Widget   a    S12345           1  -4.0  -4.0 NaN
4     wrench   a    S12360           1 -99.0 -99.0 NaN
5     wrench   b    S12370           1 -22.0 -22.0 NaN
6     wrench   c    S12350           1 -15.0 -15.0 NaN
```

Explanation:

```
In [53]: df[['Part','Rev']].isin(dfLoss[['Part','Rev']])
Out[53]:
      Part    Rev
0     True   True
1    False  False
2    False  False
3    False  False
4     True   True
5     True   True
..     ...    ...
493  False  False
494  False  False
495  False  False
496  False  False
497  False  False
498  False  False

[499 rows x 2 columns]

In [54]: df[['Part','Rev']].isin(dfLoss[['Part','Rev']]).all(1)
Out[54]:
0       True
1      False
2      False
3      False
4       True
5       True
       ...
493    False
494    False
495    False
496    False
497    False
498    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: MaxU,
Very close - I'm looking to see the Part No, Rev, and Serial No for each piece, and then next to it the aggregates for all the shipments of that Part No & Rev combination.  A quick comparison on the same row of the 'This piece' and then next to it 'Past Performance' of the same Part/Rev combo.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @SDS, can you post a desired data set?

Comment: updated online doc to show sample results here:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4xdnV0LFZI1RktqR0dVWVZEYkU
Thank you!